# Prevent sorting results by a particular field in a EasyAdmin backend

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

Good afternoon,

I'm a beginner in symfony so I started to learn about bundles. I installed and configured EasyAdminBundle and it works fine.

My question is how can I disable "sort" in one field? I mean when I click on the sort button nothing happens.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally EasyAdmin adds an option called `sortable` to each entity property. Since we don't restrict the options you can define for a property in the `config.yml` file, you can set this option explicitly for the fields you want to remove the sorting:

```
easy_admin:
    # ...
    User:
        class: ...
        list:
            fields:
                # ...
                - { property: '...', sortable: false }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I looked for this problem and I resolved my problem by adding "sortable: false" in the fields property of my config.yml. It works now, thank you again for your help.

Comment: Well, this is a bit embarrassing for me because I didn't think about this option which obviously is the best one and should always work. I'm going to delete my previous answer and add your reply. Thanks!